# Proof of Duhamel principle evans Chapter 2

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am working on the proof of theorem 2 in Chapter 2 Evans.
I understood everything except the last sensentence.
"Finally note $\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^{\infty}}\le t\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\to 0$."

Could anyone help elaborate how this could be deduced from the proof?
(In particular, I have no clue how to expand things like $\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^{\infty}}$…)

enter link description[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXYEz.png) here

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the norm $||u(x,t)||_{\infty}=||\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi(y,s)f(x-y, t-s)dyds||\leq\int_0^t|| \int_{\mathbb R^n}\Phi(y,s)f(x-y, t-s)dy||ds\leq\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb R^n}||\Phi(y,s)f(x-y, t-s)||dyds$. Then use that $|\int_{\mathbb R^n} \Phi|=1$ and you will find it.

Comment: You must to note that $||\Phi. f||_{\infty}\leq |\Phi|. ||f||_{\infty}$ and then you shall proceed.

Comment: I added my digestion to your proposed answer. Please help my confusion

Comment: Sorry, I mean $||\Phi.f||_{\infty}||=|\Phi|.||f||_{\infty}$, then $\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb R^n} ||\Phi.f||_{\infty} dyds=\int_0^t \int_{\mathbb R^n}|\Phi|||f||_{\infty}dyds$

Comment: Now you can use the fact that $\int_{\mathbb R^n}|\Phi|dy=1$

Comment: According to what you meant, I have $\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\Phi(y,s)f(x-y,t-s)|\,dyds\le \int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\Phi(y,s)|dyds ||f||_{\infty}\le t||f||_{\infty}$

Comment: What need to be done more about $\Phi$? I just think $\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\Phi(y,s)|dyds=1$

Comment: Nothing more, u've done! Sorry.